# Overriding sylius layout

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I want to override the frontend layout.html.twig, so I create a file in:

```
/var/www/sylius/app/Resources/WebBundle/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig
```

but nothing change.
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The folder for layout should be /var/www/sylius/app/Resources/**SyliusWebBundle**/views/Frontend/layout.html.twig

instead of only **WebBundle**